# Translate into FOL

Tags: logic, logic-translation

I have to translate the following statement:
$$"\text{Every teacher feels happy if all his/her students surpass their subject. }"$$
Where,

$P(x) := \text{x is a professor}$

$F(x) := \text{x feels happy}$

$S(x, y) := \text{x surpass the subject imparted by y}$

$A(x, y) := \text{x is student of y}$
$$$$
I have asked three different students and neither of us have the same answer, the four options are:
a) $\forall x\forall y\left((P(x)\wedge A(y,x)\wedge S(y,x))\rightarrow F(x)\right)$

b) $\forall x\forall y\left((P(x)\wedge (A(y,x)\rightarrow  S(y,x)) \rightarrow F(x))\right)$

c) $\forall x\left((P(x)\wedge \forall y(A(y,x)\rightarrow  S(y,x)) \rightarrow F(x))\right)$

d) $\forall x\left(\forall y(P(x)\wedge A(y,x)\wedge S(y,x))\rightarrow F(x)\right)$

I think the correct is $\textbf{c)}$, am I correct?

Comment: @Bram28: Would you *please* stop putting this tag on questions until you bring this up on meta?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, sorry ... I am not familiar with the official procedure here ... what do I need to do?

Comment: @Bram28: Yeah, obviously. Just go to meta and see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, (c) is the correct answer. It says, "for every teacher $x$, if every student of $x$'s surpasses $x$'s subject, then $x$ is happy."

Since this is logic, we should also correct a minor error in the statement: it should be, "Every teacher feels happy if all *their* students surpass their subject." (Or, "every *male* professor feels happy if all his students surpass *his* subject.")

For reference, here is why the other options are wrong:

- (a) says "for every professor and student, if $x$ is a professor and $y$ is a student of $x$'s and surpasses $x$'s subject, then $x$ is happy." This is logically equivalent to "Any professor with *at least one* student who surpasses their subject is happy", which is not saying the same thing.
- (b) is quite wrong if you look where the parentheses are nested; it is logically equivalent to "Any professor with at least one person who isn't their student but does surpass their subject is happy."
- (d) is the closest other than (c) to being correct, because it gets the placement of $\forall y$ at least correct. After moving "$P(x)$" out of the inner quantification, it says, "For every professor $x$, if all people are $x$'s student and surpass $x$'s subject, then $x$ is happy."

Comment: Yes sorry, I just translate it from Spanish, thank you!

Comment: @LukasHaring That would explain the error! Thanks for asking the question.